# Value in cell saved as list? Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'X' not found

Tags: r, function, count

I am trying to count the number of observations within a category using count(), resulting in the following error:

> count(Data$Condition, c('Low'))
>
> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Low' not found

However, when I request to return all values in this column I get the following response:

```
Data$Condition


[1] Medium Low    Low    Medium High   Zero   High   Low    High   Zero   Medium Zero   High   Low    Medium
[16] Medium Zero   Low    High   Medium Zero   High   Low    Medium High   Zero   Low    Medium High   Zero  
Levels: High Low Medium Zero
```

Thus, R should be able to retrieve the count of values that are 'Low'.

What have I done wrong? The category is already defined with:

```
Data$Condition <- as.character(Data$Condition)
```

What is also strange is that, when I export my dataframe to csv, this column (Data$Condition) is viewed as following for every cell (observation) in Excel:

> c("High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Medium",
> "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium",
> "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "High", "Low", "Medium",
> "Medium", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium")

In R, this column of the dataframe is displayed normally; so for every observation there is "Low", or "Medium" for example instead of the whole list of all observations in every cell as displayed in Excel.

So, have I accidentally saved this column as a list or something for every value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is incorrect. I think you are trying to use `count` from `plyr`, `plyr` has been retired and it is better to switch to `dplyr`. In `dplyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>% dplyr::count(Condition) %>% filter(Condition == 'Low')
```